# Embed a list of forms in Google Site per DocList

Tags: google-apps-script, google-apps-for-education

I used the code given in
[Embedding Google DocList in a Google Site](https://developers.google.com/apps-script/articles/embedding_docslist_in_sites#section1)
to embed a list of files (taken from a folder in Google drive) in a page of Google Sites. I like to know, if there's a way to modify the links on the output-page, so that they direct to the live-form of the spreadsheet and not to the spreadsheet-mode as it's set in the script.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

**EDIT :** sorry about that, forget this first answer as **there is** actually a method to get form urls !!

here is how it works

```
function myFunction() {
  var ss=SpreadsheetApp.getActive()
  var formurl = ss.getFormUrl()
  Browser.msgBox(formurl)
}
```

so it would be quite easy to embed a list in a site page,

here is a small code that does the job, online version [here](https://script.google.com/macros/s/AKfycbwkbmetwMffEoGI3_kh0Xb3XizCwDO9UiDJ-lBiwKFntt9_DroZ/exec) (needs authorization) be patient : can be slow to show up...

```
function doGet() {
  var app=UiApp.createApplication().setTitle('Available Forms').setStyleAttribute('padding', '25');
  var user = Session.getEffectiveUser().getUserLoginId();
  app.add(app.createLabel('Available forms in Drive for '+user).setStyleAttribute('background', '#dddd33').setPixelSize(500, 18).setHorizontalAlignment(UiApp.HorizontalAlignment.CENTER).setStyleAttribute('fontWeight', 'bold'))
  var flex=app.createFlexTable().setId('flex').setWidth('500').setBorderWidth(1).setCellPadding(2).setStyleAttribute('borderColor', '#dddd33');
  var index = 0
  var docs = DocsList.getAllFiles()
    for (var n in docs){
      if(docs[n].getFileType()=="spreadsheet"){
        var ss=SpreadsheetApp.openById(docs[n].getId())
         if(ss.getFormUrl()){
    flex.setText(index, 0, docs[n].getName())
    flex.setWidget(index, 1, app.createAnchor('open form', ss.getFormUrl()))
    ++ index
  }
  }
  }
  app.add(flex)
  return app
}
```

again sorry that I forgot this feature.

---

*-Forms are embedded in spreadsheet and don't appear as individual entities in your drive.  Their ID (or URL) are not available from apps-script.... I'm afraid you'll have to encode the URLs manually.-*

Comment: Ok, that's not what I want to hear, but thank you for your reply :-) Do you know if it's possible to open a form automatically when a spreadsheet is opened?

Comment: please see edit, I forgot there is actually a method for that ;-)

Answer (score 0):

You could create a Document and name it the title of your Google Form.  Stick the URL of the form inside the doc.

Comment: Yeah, but I have to do that for a lot of forms, and they are changing regularly. So I want to avoid manually copy & paste the whole bunch of form-URLs to a document.